# Get one user's data in firestore and display in Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, react-native-firebase

I am using Expo and Firebase to create an app. I am currently using this code to get the user's profile information:

```
async function getUserInfo(){
    try {
      let doc = await firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
        .get();

      if (!doc.exists){
        alert('No user data found!')
      } else {
        let dataObj = doc.data();
        alert(dataObj.FullName);
      }
    } catch (err){
    alert('There is an error.', err.message)
    }
  }
```

This way, it works. The alert is displayed. However, I am trying to display the value like this

```
   <Text>Name: {here_some_variable_for_name}</Text>
```

Here's what I have tried:

- returning the variable and then calling the function
- using ``const [fullName, setFullName] = useState(''), and setting "fullName". Here is that code:

```
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('')

  async function getUserInfo(){
    try {
      let doc = await firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
        .get();

      if (!doc.exists){
        alert('No user data found!')
      } else {
        let dataObj = doc.data();
        setFullName(dataObj.FullName);
      }
    } catch (err){
    alert('There is an error.', err.message)
    }
  }

  getUserInfo();
```

After adding the line "const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('')", the code suddenly doesn't work. When testing it in the web browser, the page is just blank.

Neither of these have worked. The data is definitely being received correctly, but the displaying part is not working.

Comment: Storing it in state (eg `useState`) is appropriate and should work. Can you share that code?

Comment: Added that code now. For whatever reason it seems like the code "const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('')" is causing the code to not work

Comment: Fetching data from Firestore is a side effect, you need to call inside `useEffect`.

`useEffect(()=>{getUserInfo()},[])`

Comment: Hmmm... Tried this with the useState, and it is still not working

Comment: Another note: I am not getting any syntax errors showing up in the expo localhost. All I am seeing is that the whole page goes blank - this is making it kind of hard to deduce why the code isn't working. What I had to do was comment out each line one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: I had forgotten to import useState, I did that and it worked.